# Canonical map $X\rightarrow K^X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $K$ is a field and $X$ a set, is there some kind of canonical map $X\rightarrow K^X=\{\text{maps }X\rightarrow K\}?$

If not, maybe only for $X\in\mathbb{N}$ or $X=n\times m$?

Comment: Well, there's the map that sends every element of $X$ to the constant $0$ function, for instance.  What sort of properties do you want the map to have?

Comment: Like @EricWofsey, but injective: map $x\in X$ to the function that maps every element of $X\setminus\{x\}$ to $0$ and maps $x$ to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map $X\to K^X$ is equivalent to a map $X\times X\to K$.  If such a map deserves to be called "canonical", it should be invariant under any bijection $X\to X$.  Given any two elements $(x,y),(x',y')\in X\times X$ there is a bijection $\sigma:X\to X$ such that $\sigma(x)=x'$ and $\sigma(y)=y'$ iff either $x\neq y$ and $x'\neq y'$ or $x=y$ and $x'=y'$.  This means that a "canonical" map $f:X\times X\to K$ can take at most two values: there is one element $a\in K$ such that $f(x,x)=a$ for all $x\in X$, and one element $b\in K$ such that $f(x,y)=b$ for all distinct $x,y\in X$.

In terms of maps $g:X\to K^X$, this means that for each $x\in X$, $g(x)$ is the map $X\to K$ that sends $x$ to $a$ and every other element of $X$ to $b$.